# Thread safe id generation with Interlocked in c#

Tags: c#, thread-synchronization, interlocked

I am trying to understand `Interlocked` in C# in thread synchronization.

```
public int MethodUsedByMultipleThreads()
{
    var id = CreateNextId();
    return id;
}

private long CreateNextId()
{
    long id = 0;
    Interlocked.Exchange(ref id , this._nextId);
    Interlocked.Increment(ref this._nextId);
    return id;
}
```

Is the line

```
Interlocked.Exchange(ref id , this._nextId);
```

redundant if I directly use

```
Interlocked.Increment(ref this._nextId);
return _nextId;
```

Will it serve the same purpose?

Comment: Generally, you want to use *one* atomic operation. It looks like you should just be using `Increment` on the shared variable and *using the return value from that operation* rather than going back to the variable again. You're defeating the point of atomic operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
Interlocked.Exchange(ref id, this._nextId);
```

is both redundant and incorrect. It is redundant because it is practically the same as:

```
id = this._nextId
```

...because the `id` is a local variable that is not shared with other threads. And it is incorrect because there is a race condition between incrementing the `_nextId` field and returning it from the method `CreateNextId()`. The correct implementation is:

```
private long CreateNextId()
{
    long id;
    id = Interlocked.Increment(ref this._nextId) - 1;
    return id;
}
```

...or simply:

```
private long CreateNextId() => Interlocked.Increment(ref this._nextId) - 1;
```

The method [`Interlocked.Increment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked.increment) increments the `_nextId` field, and returns the incremented value as an atomic operation.

The subtraction `- 1` is there to preserve the semantics of your existing code, regarding the meaning of the field `_nextId`. It might be preferable to change its name to `_lastId` or `_idSeed`, so that the `- 1` can be removed.

Answer (score 2):

```
long CreateNextId() => Interlocked.Increment(ref this._nextId);
```

This is all you need to generate sequential IDs in a thread-safe manner.

---

Do not use `_nextId` directly in any way: `return _nextId` is a mistake and will yield unpredictable results in a multithreaded environment - the value might be incremented by other threads after your call to `Increment` in the current thread.